# Count top elements in a matrix (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, threshold

I have the matrix:

```
A=[ 4 0 0 0 0
   0 3 0 0 0
   0 0 2 0 0
   0 0 0 1 0
   0 0 0 0 1 ];
```

I want to get the top k elements' values in the diag, such that the sum of these elements are larger than a predefined threshold T, whilst k is as large as possible.

```
For example: T= 0.9

            (4+3+2)/(trace(A)) = 0.818...
            (4+3+2+1)/(trace(A)) = 0.909...
```

i.e. we can get the vector of top values in A as: V= [4,3,2] and thus, k = 3.

Could anyone tell me how can I do that ?

Comment: how did you get the 10 from your D = 9/10 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `cumsum` of `diag(A)` you want to `find` the `last` element where the comparison `X./trace(A)<=T` is true. Put that together into code:

```
find(cumsum(diag(A))./trace(A)<=T,1,'last')
```

Comment: I think you have the right result, I'm just going to delete my answer, I was really confused...I guess you could add a sort descend before the cumsum to make sure the ordering.